# UITableViewCell Accessory view has blue square around it

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I've read many threads on this issue but can't seem to make it go away at all. This is the only thing I add in my `awakeFromNib` method within my custom cell class

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0/255.0 green:238.0/255.0 blue:238.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[self.cellTitle setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[self.cellTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:self.cellTitle.font.pointSize]];
```

My `cellForRowAtIndex` delegate method is simple and just adds the correct text to a certain cell so that's literally all the code i'm using for styling my cell.

Also if I set the `accessoryType` as `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` I get this result

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I set the `accessoryType` as a disclosure button. I'm not sure what's going on here but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[image: Table view cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, okay so I figured it out. In my `AppDelegate` file I was making sure that all of the buttons looked the same so I was calling `[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor(...)]` and since the `accessoryType` of a table view cell subclasses `UIButton` then that makes sense.